# Steps like wizard in HTML/CSS for mobile view

Tags: html, css

How would you make the markup for the image below? I know your valued time - so no need to actual code. I am looking for ways to see how this can be built.

If you were to make an example, keep in mind that the the paragraphs should be adjustable. The big green dot should accommodate itself according to the length of the child.

[image: Example of what I'm trying to accomplish]

Comment: It looks like job for `<ul>`

Comment: Hi Waqas, I think you're working on implementing a timeline in your project. See what I found for you.

Comment: https://codepen.io/EvanWieland/pen/ZOvORL/

Comment: https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/FdkEf/

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
        list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .shipment-progress li {
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 0 30px 32px;
    }
    .shipment-progress li::before {
        background-color: #fff;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        height: 16px;
        width: 16px;
        border: solid 2px #39a74f;
        border-radius: 100%;
        content: "";
    }
    .shipment-progress li::after {
        background-color: #39a74f;
        position: absolute;
        left: 9px;
        top: 20px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 2px;
        content: "";
    }
    .shipment-progress li:last-child::after {
        content: none;
    }
    .shipment-progress li.completed::before {
      background-color: #39a74f;
    }
    .shipment-progress li p {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: arial;
    }
```

```html
    <ul class="shipment-progress">
    <li class="completed">
    <p>Order Confirmed</p>
    </li>
    <li class="completed">
    <p>In Process</p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p>Dispatched</p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p>Delivered</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I rebuild your list structure using a simple flexbox and pseudo elements to display the circles and lines to fit your margins.

So you can insert headlines and descriptions for each steps into this list. You can change the `margin` by changeing it in the classes `wizard__steps` and `wizard__steps-description`.

```css
.wizard{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
  backgriund: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.wizard__headline{
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding-left: 64px;
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wizard__headline:after{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: green;
}

.wizard__steps{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 64px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.wizard__steps:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 16px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
}

.wizard__steps > .wizard__steps-description:last-child{
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.wizard__steps-description{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wizard">
    <div class="wizard__headline">
        <span>Step 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wizard__steps">
        <span class="wizard__steps-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </span>
        <span class="wizard__steps-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="wizard__headline">
        <span>Step 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wizard__steps">
        <span class="wizard__steps-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
            invidunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
            et ea rebum. Stet
            clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet,
            consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore
            magna aliquyam erat,
            sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
            gubergren, no
            sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="wizard__headline">
        <span>Step 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="wizard__steps">
        <span class="wizard__steps-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet
        </span>
        <span class="wizard__steps-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr
        </span>
        <span class="wizard__steps-description">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            amet, consetetur sadipscing
            elitr
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is good, I was just looking for an idea and this is enough for me to move forward. Many Thanks @michaeIT

Comment: Feel free to ask when there are any ambiguities and please mark the answer as accepted answer when it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example I made up real quick :)

Tried to make it will as little code as I could.

```css
* {
  font-family: arial
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

span {
  font-size: 22px;  
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #35a153;
  border: 5px solid #9aedb1;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 5px #fff;
  left: 0;
}

li:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #35a153;
  top: 0;
  left: 17px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Title</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac fringilla ligula, ornare tincidunt tellus. Praesent aliquam ante tempus, vestibulum orci at, posuere odio. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean placerat volutpat mi a laoreet. Suspendisse nec gravida lorem, sed sagittis lacus. Nam a congue erat. Phasellus.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Title</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec nibh sollicitudin, fermentum erat eget, dignissim velit. Quisque pretium rutrum erat ac placerat. Donec fringilla consectetur ligula, sit amet dictum felis iaculis non. Suspendisse non varius enim. Donec vel odio justo. Nam accumsan purus non ultricies fringilla. Duis pulvinar orci non turpis pulvinar accumsan. Donec finibus eu nibh a faucibus. Mauris facilisis, nisl vitae volutpat mollis, nunc lectus rutrum lacus, quis aliquet tortor tortor ornare nisl. Integer dignissim, enim consectetur dignissim porta, sapien magna rhoncus metus, lobortis faucibus erat ipsum eget sem. Sed justo elit, viverra id porta sit amet.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Title</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac fringilla ligula, ornare tincidunt tellus. Praesent aliquam ante tempus, vestibulum orci at, posuere odio.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```